# Apache follow symbolic links (Internal Server Error)

Tags: apache

My .htaccess:

```
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
AllowOverride None
```

Server returns: Internal Server Error. When I remove the second line then theres no Error but the links won't work...

Comment: And what apache's error log tells you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least part of your issue is because AllowOverride is not allowed in .htaccess files. Its context is only 'directory', which is only allowed in server configs or virtual hosts.

Having it set to 'None' (assuming it was defined in the correct location) would mean that .htaccess files would be ignored, which doesn't seem to be your intent.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride

You might want to include the plus sign with your options, this allows you to merge options, instead of the closest match taking precedence.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options

> Normally, if multiple Options could apply to a directory, then the most specific one is used and others are ignored; the options are not merged. (See how sections are merged.) However if all the options on the Options directive are preceded by a + or - symbol, the options are merged. Any options preceded by a + are added to the options currently in force, and any options preceded by a - are removed from the options currently in force.